# Bound for analytic function on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand a practice exercise we were given for class (or rather trying to find a general solution).

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the open unit disc, $D$, and continious in the closed unit disc $\bar{D}$ and let $|f(z)|\leq C$. Suppose also that $f(z)/z^n$ can be extended to be analytic in the unit disc.

Find a bound for $|f(z_0)|$ given $|z_0|<1$. We were discussing an application of Schwartz's lemma but haven't really worked out how.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Set $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$, use Schwarz's lemma to bound $g(z_0)$, and see what that implies for $f(z_0)$?

Comment: I'll try this immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, Im not sure I know how to this. $g(0)= 0$ is not necessarily satisfied as far as i see. What am I missing?

Comment: You're right, I guess what I meant is to use the maximum principle to bound $g(z_0)$, rather than Schwarz's lemma. (When $n=1$, this is the proof of Schwarz'z lemma!)

Comment: Cool. This worked and gave the result $|f(z)|\leq C|z|^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 9/25/2014 00:54 CET

I think I have a solution. However, I'd like to know if there are BETTER bounds?

As proposed by Mr. Greg Martin's comment, let $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$.

We now let $h(z)=g(z)-g(0)$, so $h(0)=0$. By the triangle inequality we have that $|h(z)|\geq |g(z)|-|g(0)|\geq g(z)-C$. And thus by Schwartz's lemma it follows that

$$|z|\geq |h(z)| \geq |g(z)|-C = |f(z)/z^n| - C.$$

Rearraning yields

$$|f(z)|\leq (|z|+C)|z^n|.$$

Is the argument valid? Is there a better solution. What scares me a bit is that I haven't found schwart'z lemma in the course book, which suggests there may be another solution.

Thanks again!

EDIT 2:

Actually it appears the maximum principle is correct way to go here. We can the even better bound of

$$|f(z)|\leq C|z|^n. \: \: (1) $$

Case closed. Thanks for the help Mr. Martin. If you decide to rewrite (1) above as an answer ill accept it. Else ill just accept my own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the offer - you can use this answer, it's fine :)